# How to Read and Write a single sector in SD Card, using Android NDK

Tags: android-ndk, sd-card, sector

How to Read and Write a single sector in SD Card, using Android NDK C/C++?
Is it possible, like this:
http://www.8051projects.net/mmc-sd-interface-fat16/reading-writing-sd-mmc-sector.php

I know it is not possible for Java.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a low-level operation not likely to be provided by the SDK, but I could be wrong I suppose. It most likely requires native code and root access. That is most likely what you will find after you investigate this.

Comment: yes, u r right, must use native. but i think even use native to access sd card sector by sector, it takes too long time. I have given this idea up.